# Why should I use the Asset Pipeline to serve images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In the Ruby on Rails guide to the Asset Pipeline, it says

> Any assets under public will be served as static files by the
>   application or web server. You should use app/assets for files that
>   must undergo some pre-processing before they are served.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

To me, this says that images should be kept in the public directory as they can be served statically by my web server and require no pre-processing.

Are there advantages to putting your images in `assets/`?

Comment: @gmoore- Wondering the same thing myself. Another thing I was thinking- the MD5 -hashed filename obscures the name of the image file somewhat, which might be hurtful in terms of getting your images indexed by Google?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asset precompile appends unique hash value to image filenames, which allows users to get latest version of it despite of cache or expire settings on the server. This is useful when you want to change images in website design.

You don't want to use `/assets/images` for images what are unlikely to change (like user uploads).

Comment: It's true that you properly don't want to use `/assets/images` for user uploads. However it's still good practice to use it for all your own images, even if you don't expect them to change (eg. a logo)! Using different folders only overcomplicate your setup without any advantages.

Answer (score 4):

Because it would harm the versatility of the asset pipeline.

With images being served via the asset pipeline, if you change the asset pipeline (for instance, have it upload files to S3) you would have to then sync your images via some other task.

There may be other, deeper reasons, but that is what would give me pause.

EDIT:
  Side note: In production thanks to assets:precompile everything from /assets/ will be served from public.

Comment: @DanielEvans - Can you explain what you mean by "changing the asset pipeline"? I didn't understand the example you gave about uploading to S3.

Comment: @Yarin Sure: It is common practice to have your application's static assets served from somewhere other than public. For instance, your deploy process might push assets to a CDN or Amazon S3. You can enhance the asset pipeline so that rake assets:precompile puts the assets where you want them. However, if you have assets stored in public/ you might have to manually adjust existing gems/scripts which do that work for you.